# Change class of many and one element

Tags: jquery

On the following code I am doing the following:

1. Get all child A tags in an "element" (links);

   ```
   var links = element.find("a");
   ```
2. Find all Divs (panes) which Id is in one of the A tags href;

   ```
   var panes = links.map(function () { 
     return $("#" + this.href.split("#")[1]); 
   });
   ```
3. When one of the links is clicked I need to remove class "active" from all panes and add "active" class to the pane which ID is the same as the clickedLink.href.split("#")[1].

   ```
   links.bind("click", function (event) {         

     panes.not("id*=" + this.href.split("#")[1]).removeClass("active");
     panes("#" + this.href.split("#")[1]).addClass("active");

   }
   ```

I am getting problems in (2) on the two "panes ..." code lines.

Could someone tell me how to do this?

Comment: Provide some html or a jsfiddle please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way of doing this is to:

1. Remove the `active` class from all of the panes
2. Just add it back to the one you want

You don't need to select within `panes` for the second part (that syntax was incorrect, but it doesn't matter); `id`s are unique in the document. So:

```
links.bind("click", function (event) {    
  $.each(panes, function() { $(this).removeClass("active") });     
  $("#" + this.href.split("#")[1]).addClass("active");
});
```

```js
var element = $(document.body);
var links = element.find("a");

var panes = links.map(function () { 
  return $("#" + this.href.split("#")[1]); 
});

console.log(panes);

links.bind("click", function (event) {         
  $.each(panes, function() { $(this).removeClass("active") });
  $("#" + this.href.split("#")[1]).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div01">div 01</div>
<div id="div02">div 02</div>
<div id="div03">div 03</div>
<div id="div04">div 04</div>
<div id="div05">div 05</div>

<a href="#div01">link to div 01</a>
<a href="#div02">link to div 02</a>
<a href="#div03">link to div 03</a>
<a href="#div04">link to div 04</a>
<a href="#div05">link to div 05</a>
```